# How to enable code contracts in Visual studio 2008?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, code-contracts

I am (mainly) a .NET developer and for my project I use visual studio 2008. After watching this video:
http://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/Peli/Getting-started-with-Code-Contracts-in-Visual-Studio-2008

it became clear for me that I want to use code contracts. This video page includes a link to to devlabs where I can download the required resources for visual studio 2010 and later:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/devlabs/dd491992.aspx

Where do I get the required resources for visual studio 2008? I know the principle now (clearly explained on channel 9) but it is not clear to me how I can enable it in visual studio 2008.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the download is for every non express version of Visual Studio (2008 included). The two links for 2010 and 2012 are just for the IDE extensions, to enable intellisense and code snippets.